# intent extras are duplicated when using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in PendingIntent when creating android notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I want to create several notifications that launches an activity (or refresh it) to display a product description.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.applicationicon,
            Resources.getString("NewSaleNotification", context),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
// Hide the notification after its selected
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainApplication.class);
intent.putExtra("saleid", saleid);

// to be sure the activity won't be restarted
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, SaleTitle, SaleMessage, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(saleid, notification);
```

When I create the PendingIntent, I have 4 choices : FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_ONE_SHOT and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

The definition of the last one (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) is what I want to do but it doesn't work as it should. If I create 2 notifications, they both have the same 'saleid' extra which is the latest one. How can I make more than one notification with different 'saleid' extra?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> but it doesn't work as it should

Yes, it does.

> If I create 2 notifications, they both have the same 'saleid' extra which is the latest one.

This is precisely what [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) says is supposed to happen.

> How can I make more than one notification with differents 'saleid' extra?

Option #1: Put a different action string in each of your `Intents`. This will make them different (from the standpoint of `filterEquals()`) and give them separate `PendingIntents`. However, since you are specifying the component in the `Intent` (`MainApplication.class`), the action will not affect how the `Intent` is routed.

Option #2: Use a different `requestCode` (2nd parameter) on your `getActivity()` calls. While this is documented as "currently not used", it does result in different `PendingIntent` objects being returned. However, since this behavior is undocumented, it may change in the future.

Comment: Option #2 is absolutely the solution I was looking for, to the extent I'm tempted to run around Stack Overflow and point everyone to this answer.

It's fustrating to have "different" notifications pass identical Extras (the latest) to their Activity when selected. This fixes it. For now.

Comment: settings different action solved my issue, thanks for the answer