# Clarification on the docs for PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Tags: android

From the [documentation of Pending Intent `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) in Android:

> by canceling the previous pending intent, this ensures that only entities given the new data will be able to launch it. If this assurance is not an issue, consider FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Can anyone explain what this line means?

Comment: @VikalpPatel - your edit was wrong - the OP was right - please be careful

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Once you create a new `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, anything holding a previous `PendingIntent` for the same `Intent` will no longer be able to execute that original `PendingIntent`.

For example, suppose we have this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);

i.putExtra("key", 1);

PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
```

and we use that `PendingIntent` with, say, a `Notification`.

Later on, we execute:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);

i.putExtra("key", 2);

PendingIntent pi2=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

At this point, the `PendingIntent` created originally (`pi`) is no longer valid, and whatever we use `pi2` for will see the updated extra value (`2`).

If, instead, we did:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);

i.putExtra("key", 2);

PendingIntent pi2=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

At this point, `pi` and `pi2` both represent the *same* `PendingIntent`, and both will see the updated extra value (`2`).

Or, if we did:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);

i.putExtra("key", 2);

PendingIntent pi2=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
```

At this point, `pi` and `pi2` still represent the same `PendingIntent`, but the extras are unchanged, as `getActivity()` returns the *original* `PendingIntent` without applying the new extras.

Most times, `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is a fine answer when you are trying to replace extras inside a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);
    i.putExtra("key", 1);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager am =     Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(ELAPSED_REALTIME,mTime,pi);

    Intent i=new Intent(this, Foo.class);
    i.putExtra("key", 2);
    PendingIntent  pi2=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.set(ELAPSED_REALTIME,mTime1,pi2);

So, now when alarm manager expires at time mTime, the pending intent  pi won't be called ?

Comment: @pikini: I would expect that `PendingIntent.CanceledException` would be thrown. Presumably, `AlarmManager` has logic to deal with this. If you want to cancel an alarm, though, it is better to call `cancel()` rather than just letting `AlarmManager` deal with the exception, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try out doing this and share my results. Thanks for your time to reply back.

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT `At this point, pi and pi2 both represent the same PendingIntent, and both will see the updated extra value (2).` Suppose if they both are register with a alarm manager and when alarm time reaches will BOTH gets executed and what if PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT is used for above case?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: "Suppose if they both are register with a alarm manager and when alarm time reaches will BOTH gets executed" -- for truly equivalent `PendingIntent` objects, the second alarm would unschedule the first alarm. You cannot have two outstanding alarms for equivalent `PendingIntent` objects.

Comment: What if i want to keep both trigger even then what should I use instead of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: @LokeshTiwari: They have to be different `PendingIntent` objects. Pass different `int` values as the second parameter to `getActivity()`, `getService()`, or `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: If I set different Action on the Intent, would that be same or different Intent?

Comment: @MostafaImran: Two `Intents` with different action strings are two different `Intents` -- they are not equivalent `Intents`.

Comment: @CommonsWare how I can test it? I have created one pending Intent and add it with notification. then I use same intent with pending Intent and add FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT but I didn't add this pendingIntent2 to notification and clicking on notification Intent didn't execute or open the activity as you mentioned in Intent(); here is the example link I use. https://pastebin.com/WKz8Ganc

Comment: @UnKnown: Please open separate questions when you have enough source code to warrant a pastebin. In your case, you cancelled the `PendingIntent` in the `Notification`, but you then threw away your new `PendingIntent`. Android does not go around and find all occurrences of the old `PendingIntent` and replace it with the new one. Either use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or re-raise the `Notification` with the new `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Can you give me link from where you read it? `Android does not go around and find all occurrences of the old PendingIntent and replace it with the new one.`

Comment: To anyone stumbling here because their Intents are not firing, they're most likely overriding one another. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824534/2445763) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688505/2445763) for adding uniqueness to your Intents.