# Multiple Pending Intents?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

My activity creates a couple of notifications.

Here's how I'm currently doing it, on different resultIntents:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
  PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
  );
```

Now, since a flag is compulsory, I'm forced to select from [the four flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT). What do I do if I want all of them to work independently, and the newer notification isn't affected by the previous one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution was found here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the#comment3283736_3168653).

You've to use setAction on the intent to a unique value so that there will be no matching PendingIntents

Here's what I used:

```
setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

Comment: This makes no sense. If you are always setting the ACTION to a unique value, setting `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is useless, since there will **never be a matching `PendingIntent`**. Setting a unique ACTION string guarantees that the call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` will **always** return a new `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually required. I was looking for a way to never have a matching PendingIndent. The answer has the flag just because I quoted it from another stackoverflow answer. Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Comment: You can edit your answer and remove the flag. As I said, the flag makes no sense and is likely to confuse other people.

Answer (score 4):

From the official documentation

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

`Intent.filterEquals` documentation:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

If you need an unlimited amount of PendingIntents, I would recommend using `Intent.setData` to some sort of unique value. If you can group them, use `setType` or `addCategory` to reduce the number of unique PendingIntents needed.