# Notification looses track of activity when cleared from recent apps

Tags: android, android-notifications

My activity looses the track of its notification when the application is removed from the recent apps
My notification code :

`builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Started").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        targetIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        targetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build());`

I have to restart the app after that and the notification doesn't open the activity any more.

Any leads on this ???

Comment: why you are using FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT?refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043206/clarification-on-the-docs-for-pendingintent-flag-cancel-current

Comment: I want to override the function called when the app is cleared from the recent apps

Comment: what do you want exactly i am not understanding your problem?

Comment: my problem is that my activity is not showing up when i clear it from the recent apps. The linking between the app and the notification is cleared by the OS

Comment: Use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: i used that. no help

Comment: it works absolutely fine when i close the application. the problem comes when i close it from the recent apps,

Comment: Not yet, but I guess there applications supporting this functionality.

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni did you solve this issue? Same issue here :(