# Two active notification with different extras

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I need to create 2 notification but both of them get the same extra, if I use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT the last, otherwise the first.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

for(int num=1;num<3;num++){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNotification.class); 
    intent .putExtra("reminder_id", num);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num, intent , 0);
    // PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(num, noti);          
}
```

How can I have different extras? Or in general, how can my ActivityNotification know which notification called it?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538554/281545) :

- Option #1: Put a different action string in each of your Intents. In
  your code :

  ```
  intent.putExtra("reminder_id", num);
  intent.setAction("com.yourapplic.intent.action.ACTION_NAME" + num);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num, intent , 0);
  ```
- Option #2: Use a different requestCode (2nd parameter) on your getActivity() calls. This apparently does not work in your case